# Session Variable is null after using RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

After editing information in view `Edit.cshtml`, I set a session variable `Session["ToastMessage"] = "Sucessfully";` to show it in `Edit.cshtml` after that is loaded again. But I got `Session["ToastMessage"] = null` in View.

```
        // GET: About/Edit/
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            AboutInformation about = LoadDataFromConfigFile();
            return View(about);
        }

        // POST: About/Edit/
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "NameApp,ContactInformation,Email,Fax,Phone,ReleaseDay,LogoPathOfProduction,IsShow,LatestVersion,ReleaseNotes")] AboutInformation about,List<string> imagesToDelete, List<HttpPostedFileBase> images, bool? isShowInfo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //update....
            }

            Session["ToastMessage"] = "Sucessfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Edit");
        }
```

Tried to debug, it showed `Session["ToastMessage"] = null` when it is just passed to Get method:

```
  // GET: About/Edit/
            public ActionResult Edit()
            {
            }
```

Session is clear somehow, have been using Session a lots in my app, and it worked fine. Does ASP just clear session at any random time?
Need help!

Comment: You can use TempData, as suggested in answers below. Further you can use it's Keep or Peek method to make it available in other action methods also. but i don't think you will need it a because it's a Toast message.

Comment: I think both TempData and Session work fine for this case. I already tried TempData but it got null the same which when I used Session. Wonder what makes the value becomes null. @Sid

Comment: You need to use keep, because here this is going from one method to another action method. So for this it will be like: TempData.Keep("ToastMessage"); in your edit method before returning. And then read it again in your Get method.

Answer (score 1):

With your case, you can use `TempData` instead of `Session`.

```
TempData["ToastMessage"] = "Sucessfully";
```

TempData can be used to store temporary data which can be used in the subsequent request.

```
public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            var result = TempData["ToastMessage"];
            // check result here
            AboutInformation about = LoadDataFromConfigFile();
            return View(about);
        }
```

Comment: I think both TempData and Session work fine for this case. I already tried TempData but it got null the same which when I used Session. Wonder what makes the value becomes null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TempData while redirect to one ActionMethod to Another Action.

```
var Status=TempData["ToastMessage"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @hien-nguyen answer to directly return to view and show the toast message. However in your case you are redirecting to another action method.
So, You can use Keep method of Temp data like this:

```
// POST: About/Edit/
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "NameApp,ContactInformation,Email,Fax,Phone,ReleaseDay,LogoPathOfProduction,IsShow,LatestVersion,ReleaseNotes")] AboutInformation about,List<string> imagesToDelete, List<HttpPostedFileBase> images, bool? isShowInfo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //update....
        }

        TempData["ToastMessage"] = "Sucessfully";
        var message = TempData["ToastMessage"];
        TempData.Keep("ToastMessage");
        return RedirectToAction("Edit");
    }
```

And in Get Method:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            AboutInformation about = LoadDataFromConfigFile();
            var message = TempData["ToastMessage"];
            return View(about);
        }
```

Comment: just tried TempData.Keep, and still get null in Get method.

Answer (score 0):

Check for your localhost browser cookies or any server you are using; they should not be blocked. Allow cookies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30648381)